# Why & When should I use SPARSE COLUMN? (SQL SERVER 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008

After going thru some tutorials on SQL Server 2008's new feature "SPARSE COLUMN", I have found that it doesn't take any space if the column value is 0 or NULL but when there is a value, it takes 4 times the space a regular(non sparse) column holds.

If my understanding is correct, then why I will go for that at the time of database design?
And if I use that, then at what situation will I be?

Also out of curiosity, how does no space get reserved when a column is defined as sparse column (I mean to say, what is the internal implementation for that?)

Comment: This link from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) has tabular details showing space savings w.r.t. each data type. Can be a really good pointer in this regard.

Comment: A very good read on sparse columns in general [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/null-friendly-using-sparse-columns-and-column-sets-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

A sparse column doesn't use **4x the amount of space** to store a value, it uses a (fixed) **4 extra bytes** per non-null value. (As you've already stated, a NULL takes 0 space.)

- So a non-null value stored in a *bit* column would be 1 bit + 4 bytes = 4.125 bytes. But if 99% of these are NULL, it is still a net savings.
- A non-null value stored in a *GUID (UniqueIdentifier)* column is 16 bytes + 4 bytes = 20 bytes. So if only 50% of these are NULL, that's still a net savings.

So the "expected savings" depends strongly on what *kind* of column we're talking about, and your estimate of what ratio will be null vs non-null. Variable width columns (varchars) are probably a little more difficult to predict accurately.

This [Books Online Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) has a table showing *what percentage* of different data types would need to be null for you to end up with a benefit.

So *when* should you use a Sparse Column? When you expect a significant percentage of the rows to have a NULL value. Some examples that come to mind:

- A "**Order Return Date**" column in an order table. You would hope that a very small percent of sales would result in returned products.
- A "**4th Address**" line in an Address table. Most mailing addresses, even if you need a   Department name and a "Care Of" probably don't need 4 separate lines.
- A "**Suffix**" column in a customer table. A fairly low percent of people have a "Jr." or "III" or "Esquire" after their name.

Comment: There was a suggested edit that it is 4 extra bytes per non-null *field*. This is incorrect, I've rolled this back to say *row*. 
To clarify with an example: if we have a 100-row table with a GUID field, 10 rows of which have values, 90 rows are NULL. A GUID field is normally 16 bytes, so a normal (non-sparse) GUID would be 16*100 = 1600 bytes. If we made this a sparse field, the space used would instead be only (16+4)*10 = 200 bytes, not (16*10)+4 = 164 bytes. The 4-byte penalty applies to every populated row.

Comment: But surely, if there are multiple sparse fields in a row, the 4-byte penalty applies to each of the *fields* separately? In which case it would be more natural to say *per field* (which would really mean *per field per row*). It actually took me quite a while to realize your understanding of *per field* was *per field per table*.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to calculate the predicted penalty separately for multiple sparse fields in the same table. 

I guess it would make sense to evaluate them together if you expect them to coincide (like if you have 5 fields that are only populated if a product gets returned or something).

Comment: Row feels very misleading to me. Tables have columns, records have fields, correct? 4 bytes per non-null column might be ambiguous, but I don't think 4 bytes per non-null field is. As it is this answer implies there is a 4 byte cap per record, no matter how many non-null sparse fields it has.

Comment: I get your point, @OGHaza, I've always used "column" and "field" interchangeably, so I'm not sure if everyone would understand the distinction based on those terms alone. But yes, you'd get multiple penalties if you had multiple sparse columns in a table. I guess I assumed this would be obvious, the "it" in my very first sentence is really "each sparse column". I'll think about how to clarify the answer.

Comment: @OGHaza Regarding [Rows vs Records](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31805/what-is-the-difference-between-a-record-and-a-row-in-sql-server)

Comment: ypercube aha so my terminology is all over the place :P @BradC, having read your comment, and then reread the above I do see what you mean and actually your phrasing seems about right. Apologies

Comment: I've edited some of the terminology in the answer to make it more clear, and hopefully avoid the field/row/column confusion.

Comment: Space is not the only thing you should be considering. Update load is also important - remember, any time you null out or bring in a value, you're changing the row length and hence having to potentially rebuild, and possibly split, your page. So while a person's name suffix or an address line 4 is still a good candidate for sparse, return date might not be - if you're say Amazon you would probably be happier chewing up the space to reduce the cost of updates.

Comment: @OGHaza Actually, ypercube's meta link is an example of why you can't ask random people for a definition and expect a correct definition.  The most up voted answer takes two people's personal definition and presents it as truth, the next two take a survey of terms in documentation, and the next three are unsupported opinions.  While they do a good job of pointing out what a record is, they fail to provide backup for what it is not, what a record is, what to call where a value is in a row, or provide any documentation defining the terms Row, Record, and Field.

Answer (score 27):

- Storing a null in a sparse column takes up no space at all.
- To any external application the column will behave the same
- Sparse columns work really well with filtered indexes as you will only want to create an index to deal with the non-empty attributes in the column.
- You can create a column set over the sparse columns that returns an xml clip of all of the non-null data from columns covered by the set.  The column set behaves like a column itself. Note: you can only have one column set per table.
- Change Data Capture and Transactional replication both work, but not the column sets feature.

***Downsides***

- If a sparse column has data in it it will take 4 more bytes than a normal column e.g. even a bit (0.125 bytes normally) is 4.125 bytes and unique identifier rises form 16 bytes to 20 bytes.
- Not all data type can be sparse: text, ntext, image, timestamp, user-defined data type, geometry, or geography or varbinray (max) with the FILESTREAM attribute cannot be sparse. (Changed17/5/2009 thanks Alex for spotting the typo)
- computed columns can't be sparse (although sparse columns can take part in a calculation in another computed column)
- You can't apply rules or have default values.
- Sparse columns cannot form part of a clustered index.  If you need to do that use a computed column based on the sparse column and create the clustered index on that (which sort of defeats the object).
- Merge replication doesn't work.
- Data compression doesn't work.
- Access (read and write) to sparse columns is more expensive, but I haven't been able to find any exact figures on this.

[Reference](http://blogs.technet.com/andrew/archive/2008/02/28/sql-server-2008-sparse-columns.aspx)

Comment: Thanks .. I already covered that site. But even in that site failed to answer the questions which I have asked here. In which situation should I go with sparse column when it takes 4 times extra space!

Answer (score 4):

You're reading it wrong - it never takes 4x the space.

Specifically, it says 4* (4 bytes, see footnote), not 4x (multiply by 4).  The only case where it's exactly 4x the space is a char(4), which would see savings if the NULLs exist more than 64% of the time.

"*The length is equal to the average of the data that is contained in the type, plus 2 or 4 bytes."

Answer (score 1):

```
| datetime NULL      | datetime SPARSE NULL | datetime SPARSE NULL |
|--------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 20171213 (8 bytes) | 20171213 (12 bytes)  | 20171213 (12 bytes)  |
| NULL     (8 bytes) | 20171213 (12 bytes)  | 20171213 (12 bytes)  |
| 20171213 (8 bytes) | NULL      (0 bytes)  | NULL      (0 bytes)  |
| NULL     (8 bytes) | NULL      (0 bytes)  | NULL      (0 bytes)  |
```

You lose 4 bytes not just once per row; but for every cell in the row that is not null.

Answer (score 0):

From [SQL SERVER – 2008 – Introduction to SPARSE Columns – Part 2](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/14/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-sparse-columns-part-2/) by [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/):

> All SPARSE columns are stored as one XML column in database. Let us
>   see some of the advantage and disadvantage of SPARSE column.
>
> **Advantages of SPARSE column are:**
>
> - INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements can reference the sparse columns by name. SPARSE column can work as one XML column as well.
> - SPARSE column can take advantage of filtered Indexes, where data are filled in the row.
> - SPARSE column saves lots of database space when there are zero or null values in database.
>
> **Disadvantages of SPARSE column are:**
>
> - SPARSE column does not have IDENTITY or ROWGUIDCOL property.
> - SPARSE column can not be applied on text, ntext, image, timestamp, geometry, geography or user defined datatypes.
> - SPARSE column can not have default value or rule or computed column.
> - Clustered index or a unique primary key index can not be applied SPARSE column. SPARSE column can not be part of clustered index key.
> - Table containing SPARSE column can have maximum size of 8018 bytes instead of regular 8060 bytes. A table operation which involves SPARSE
>     column takes performance hit over regular column.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a place for protracted discussion .. additionally, you answered rather late basically just summarizing information that was already neatly summarized and accepted. I'm not removing this, as it does answer the question, but the community might react negatively to it.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/14/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-sparse-columns-part-2/

Comment: I'm going to upvote this.  The explanation of all the sparse fields being held in one XML field clears things up in my head a bit.  No-one else mentioned that.

Comment: @Brain2000 probably because it is incorrect. This is how sparse columns are actually stored. http://improve.dk/sparse-column-storage-ndash-the-sparse-vector/. They can be returned to the client as XML if using column sets,