# Is SPARSE the best way to implement an SQL column union?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a table with 19 nullable columns in which only one column on each record is assigned a non-null value, kind of like a C union.  Is this an ideal case for using SPARSE?  Is there a better alternative?  Each column is a (integer) foreign key, so I don't think we want to try merging them into one column because we want the relationships to other entities to be clearly and simply defined.

In case you're wondering why we have this design, it's for serial number tracking.  We have one record for every transaction that can occur on a serial number.  There are 19 different kinds of transactions we care about (recorded in 19 different tables).  We want to be able to refer to any of those transactions.

Comment: You should take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398453/why-when-should-i-use-sparse-column-sql-server-2008

Comment: The query optimiser is very good at dealing with null values in columns. Are you trying to get 1 result set for all the joined values unioned?

Comment: What is the reason for this design?  Can you give a cut down example? Maybe you need the supertype/subtype pattern instead?

Comment: @Lamak I did look at that question before posting my question.  It didn't answer my question.  But surely people interested in this answer are likely to be interested in that one.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - Do these different transaction types have different attributes?

Comment: @MartinSmith I added some info about why we have this design. Is it clear? If you still think the design is not ideal, I can explain more why we chose it, or maybe you will have a truly better design in mind.  We don't have the option of using the supertype/subtype pattern because the tables we're linking to are using table per class design, and those aren't part of our schema (we're an extension). So we can't change that part of the schema.

Comment: If you can't change it then yes I'd look at sparse columns then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the BOL section [Estimated Space Savings by Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) you should consider `SPARSE` for `INT` columns if at least 64% are `NULL`.

You have 94.7% `NULL` so seems like you could benefit from this to me. This does seem an unusual design though.

Comment: I already knew that the space savings would be there, so SPARSE is better than nothing. I was just wondering if there was a better alternative.