# Entity Framework with sparse tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sparse-matrix, database-normalization

My data table is sparse, therefore the data is stored as such:

```
RowId  |  Field  |  Value
  1    ,"Field1",    1.00
  1    ,"Field2",    2.00
  1    ,"Field4",    4.00
  2    ,"Field1",    1.00
  2    ,"Field3",    3.00
```

And several rows in the DB should be handled as a single object.
for example:

```
Model obj=new Model(1);//where 1 refers to the RowId
obj.Field1=1;//should update the relevant row
obj.Field2=0;//should delete the relevant row (assuming 0 is the default value)
obj.Field3=3;//should create a new row
```

How can I use entity framework to encapsulate this behavior ?

Comment: Instead of using key-value pairs, you should check [Sparse Columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx). What you call a "sparse table" is generally considered a bad design (and very inefficient). An ORM can't fix this without causing even more headaches. At the very least: How can you map to fields when you can't ever know how many fields there are without reading everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've illustrated is not a sparse table, its an [Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) table. Entity Framework does not support EAV modeling, and it's probably just as well as it can lead to major [performance issues](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10984467).

If your attributes are not dynamic then you can model your data in a more conventional manner and use [Sparse Columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx), though they have their own [pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398453/why-when-should-i-use-sparse-column-sql-server-2008).

Given the way that Entity Framework works, for anything but the most trivial of applications you can kiss 3rd Normal Form goodbye.