# Optimum indexs/constraint for multiple null columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a Valuations table defined like this:-

```
ID (PK, int, not null)  
AssetID (FK, int, null)  
LiabilityID (FK, int, null)  
ProviderFundID (FK, int, null)  
ClientFundID (FK, int, null)  
ValuationDate (date, not null)  
Value(money, not null)
```

The idea is that only one of the `FK` columns will be not null in a given row. 
Also the row must be unique for a given `ValuationDate` (no time is stored).
More `FKs` may be added in future.

The SQL server is likely to be SQL 2014 `Sql Express` but Azure may also be used.

I am planning to do regular `Upserts` from a `Temp table` which may contain thousands of rows at a time. The Valuations table will not be pruned so that charts can be created showing valuations over time so I expected millions of rows eventually.

Only my app will be writing to the database so I could, in theory, keep integrity at the app level if that helps.

How should I apply indexes/constraints to this table to keep it performant?
(If you think this design is not the best, other suggestions are welcome)

Comment: For null columns, use `sparse column` property. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398453/why-when-should-i-use-sparse-column-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this requirement

> The idea is that only one of the FK columns will be not null in a
>   given row. Also the row must be unique for a given ValuationDate (no time 
>   is stored).

I would use one of following solutions:

[1] Keeping current design I would define following CHECK constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Valuations 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Valuations_CheckForeignKeysNULLability
CHECK (
AssetID IS NOT NULL AND LiabilityID IS NULL AND ProviderFundID IS NULL AND ClientFundID IS NULL  
OR
AssetID IS NULL AND LiabilityID IS NOT NULL AND ProviderFundID IS NULL AND ClientFundID IS NULL  
OR
AssetID IS NULL AND LiabilityID IS NULL AND ProviderFundID IS NOT NULL AND ClientFundID IS NULL  
OR
AssetID IS NULL AND LiabilityID IS NULL AND ProviderFundID IS NULL AND ClientFundID IS NOT NULL 
)
```

and also following UNIQUE index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_Valuations_ValuationDate_AssetID_LiabilityID_ProviderFundID_ClientFundID
ON dbo.Valuations (ValuationDate, AssetID, LiabilityID, ProviderFundID, ClientFundID)
INCLUDE (Value)
```

[2] Second solution is use a type-subtype / superclass-subclass approach thus:

[2.1] A type table will keep all common columns:

```
dbo.Object(ID PRIMARY KEY, Type, ... common columns ... ) 
+ 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... ON dbo.(ID, Type)
```

where Type = {1=Asset, 2=Liability, 3 ...}

and [2.2] for every type I would create a separate table which will include only specific columns):

```
dbo.Asset(ID PK + FK, Type, ... specific columns to assets ...)
+
ALTER TABLE dbo.Asset
ADD CONSTRAINT ...
FOREIGN KEY (ID, Type)
REFERENCES dbo.Object(ID, Type)
```

and

```
dbo.Liability(ID PK + FK, Type, ... specific columns to liabilities ...)
+
ALTER TABLE dbo.Liability
ADD CONSTRAINT ...
FOREIGN KEY (ID, Type)
REFERENCES dbo.Object(ID, Type)
```

etc.

And Valuations table :

```
dbo.Valuations(ID PK, IDObject - FK, ValuationDate, Value)
+
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... ON dbo.Valuations (ValuationDate, IDObject)
INCLUDE (Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach;

```
            create table dbo.Valuations
                (
                ID int identity(1,1),
                DataTypeId tinyint,
                UniqueId int,
                ValuationDate date,
                Value money
                )
            go
            create table dbo.DataType
                (
                DataTypeId int,
                Data varchar(100)
                )
            go
            insert into dbo.DataType
            select 1,'Asset'
            insert into dbo.DataType
            select 2,'Liability'
            insert into dbo.DataType
            select 3,'ProviderFund'
            insert into dbo.DataType
            select 4,'ClientFund'
            go
            -- Now insert an 'asset' (for example) like this;
            insert dbo.Valuations(DataTypeId,UniqueId,ValuationDate,Value)
            select
                DataTypeId=1, -- this lookups the correct 'type' in the 'dbo.DataType' table
                UniqueId=98,-- whatever this is
                ValuationDate='20170725',
                Value=88.99
```

This way, you are capturing exactly the data you need. No need to have 3 NULL columns always.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. However, in my case I use LLBLGen and use Prefetch Paths to, optionally, bring back Valuations for an item whilst fetching it and it needs the FKs for that.