# how to query the value that has changed +/- 10% of the value from first encounter of each patient in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query that finds users with multiple hospital visits.

Table has about 593 columns, so I don't think I can show you the structure. But let's assume these are basic patients table with following columns. 
`id, sex, studyDate, referringPhysician, bmi, bsa, height, weight, bloodPressure, heartRate`. These are also in the real table.

The patient visits the hospital and has some worked done. What we would like to find is how much of patient's bmi has changed since the first encounter. For example, 

  `ID       |SEX| StudyDate  | Physician|BMI| BSA  | ht| Wt  | BP     | HR  |
1 PatientA | M | 2017-09-11 | Dr. Hale | 60| 2.03 | 6 | 282 | 116/82 | 77  |
2 PatientA | M | 2017-12-11 | Dr. Hale | 58| 2.03 | 6 | 296 | 126/82 | 72  |
3 PatientA | M | 2018-03-17 | Dr. Hale | 50| 2.03 | 6 | 282 | 126/82 | 72  |`

In the example above, row 1 was the first encounter and the BMI was 60. In row 2, the bmi decreased to 58, but it's not more than 10%. So, that shouldn't be displayed. However, row 3 has bmi 50 which is decreased by more than 10% of bmi in row 1. That should be displayed.

I'm sorry, I don't have the data that I can share.

```
with G as(
    select * from Patients P
    inner join (
        select count(*) as counts, ID as oeID
        from Patients 
        group by ID
        Having count(*) > 2
    ) oe on P.ID = oe.oeID where P.BMI > 30
)
select * from G
order by StudyDate asc;
```

From this, what I'd like to do is find out patients whose BMI has changed by 10% from the first encounter.

How can I do this?

Can you also help me understand the concept of `for-each users` in SQL, and how it handles such queries?

Comment: Can't answer without quite a bit more detail.  Table layout and sample data (does the data store each visit in the patient table?) would also help

Comment: @Twelfth I added a sample data.

Comment: Perfect...I think I got your query.  Medical analytics is something I'm trying to get into.   Your data model design could use some improvement here as you have alot of redundant data...very flat, changing this to a star schema would help in the future.

Comment: @Twelfth, thank you. Looking at your query it seems like it does what I was looking for. I'll give it a try. Unfortunately, I have no control over the database. It belongs to a third-party company, and they have only granted readonly.

Comment: brutal...almost worth making the case that you want a data feed out of that 3rd party db and into your own data warehouse so you can do some normalization.  Whomever created that wasn't a db programmer.

Comment: I absolutely agree. In fact, most of the columns are NULL for which they're not capturing the value, but there's another TEXT column where multiple values are included as a free text. it makes NO SENSE at all.

Comment: Off chance they are using sparse columns?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398453/why-when-should-i-use-sparse-column-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing at your data model here...I suspect you've got a heavily denormalized structure here with everything being crammed into one table.  You would be far better off to have a patient table separate from the table that stores their visits.  The with G syntax here is very unneeded as well, especially if you are just doing a select * from the table after.  Heh, I'm trying to get into medical analytics, so will give this a try.

I'll build this as I see your data model...you may have to change a step here and there to fit your column names.  Lets start by getting first and most recent (last) visit dates by id

```
select id, min(StudyDate) as first_visit, max(studydate) as last_visit
from patients 
group by id
having min(StudyDate) <> max(StudyDate)
```

Simply query at this point and by using the having clause we ensure that these are two separate visits.  But we are lacking the BMI numbers for these visits...so we will have to join back to the patient table to grab them.  We will iunclude a where clause to ensure only the +/- of 10% is found

```
select a.id, a.first_visit, a.last_visi, b.bmi as first_bmi, c.bmi as last_bmi, b.bmi - c.bmi as bmi_change
from
(select id, min(StudyDate) as first_visit, max(studydate) as last_visit
from patients 
group by id
having min(StudyDate) <> max(StudyDate) a
inner join patients b on b.id = a.id and b.study_date = a.first_visit
inner join patients c on c.id = a.id and c.study_date = a.last_visit
where  b.bmi - c.bmi >= 10 or  b.bmi - c.bmi  <= -10
```

Hopefully that makes sense, you'll want to change the top select line to grab all the fields you actually want to return, I'm just returning the ones of interest to your question

Part 2:

Lets approach this from a similar angle:

```
select id, min(StudyDate) as first_visit
from patients 
group by id
```

Now we've got the first visit date.  Lets join back to patients and get the bmi here.

```
select a.id, first_visit, p.bmi
from
(select id, min(StudyDate) as first_visit
from patients 
group by id) a
inner join patients b on a.first_visit = b.studydate and a.id = b.id
```

This will simply be a list of each patient by ID giving us their first_visit date and their BMI on that first visit.  Now we want to compare this bmi to all subsequent visits...so lets join all rows to back to this query.  Subquery a below is simply the query above in brackets:

```
select a.id, a.first_visit, b.study_date, a.bmi, b.bmi, a.bmi-b.bmi as bmi_change
from
(select a.id, first_visit, b.bmi
from
(select id, min(StudyDate) as first_visit
from patients 
group by id) a
inner join patients b on a.first_visit = b.studydate and a.id = b.id) a
inner join patients b on a.id = b.id
where a.bmi - b.bmi >= 10 or a.bmi - b.bmi <= -10
```

Similar idea, instead of joining on the max_date to get most recent, we are joining to all records for that patient and running the math from there.  In the commented example, this will give rows 3,5,6.

Part 3

A little more complex...getting rows 3,4,5,6 when row 4 shows less than a 10 change in BMI means you are now trying to pick out the first date that the 10 change is seen and displaying all records from that.  Lets call the query in part 2 subquery a and go pseudo code for a moment:

```
Select id, min(studydate)
from (subquerya) a
```

(subquerya) simply stands for the entire query used at the end of part 2.  This will grab the study date of the first time a bmi change of over 10 is detected for each patient id (in our comment example, it would be visit 3).  Now we can join back to patients, this time getting all records that are equal to or more recent than the min(studydate) of the first time bmi changed more than 10 since the first visit

```
select a.id, b.studydate, b.bmi
from
(Select id, min(studydate) as min_studydate
from (subquerya) a) a
inner join patients b on a.id = b.id and a.min_studydate <= b.studydate
```

This will bring back the list of all study dates happening after the first time a bmi change more than 10 was detected (3,4,5,6 from our comment example).  Of course we've now lost the first study date's bmi value, so lets add that back in and bring the query all together.

```
select a.id, b.studydate, b.bmi, c.bmi as start_bmi, c.bmi - b.bmi as bmi_change
from
(Select id, min(studydate) as min_studydate
from ( select a.id, a.first_visit, b.study_date, a.bmi, b.bmi, a.bmi-b.bmi as bmi_change
from
(select a.id, first_visit, b.bmi
from
(select id, min(StudyDate) as first_visit
from patients 
group by id) a
inner join patients b on a.first_visit = b.studydate and a.id = b.id) a
inner join patients b on a.id = b.id
where a.bmi - b.bmi >= 10 or a.bmi - b.bmi <= -10) a) a
inner join patients b on a.id = b.id and a.min_studydate <= b.studydate
inner join (select a.id, first_visit, p.bmi 
from
(select id, min(StudyDate) as first_visit
from patients 
group by id) a
inner join patients b on a.first_visit = b.studydate and a.id = b.id) c on c.id = a.id
```

If I have everything right, this should bring back rows 3,4,5,6 and the change in BMI across each visit.  I've left a few more columns in there than need be and it could be cleaned a little, but all logic should be there.  I don't have

Comment: Quick question. It seems like this would work if there were only two rows for patient. What if there are 8 rows per patient for which 6 of them had change in bmi more than 10%, for example?

Comment: @user1828605 It uses the most recent visit (max(studydate)) and the first visit (min(studydate))...ignores the visits in between.  did you want 1 rows per user/visit that was over a 10 change in bmi?  So first visit is a 60, second is a 58, third 50, 4th 51, 5th and 6th of 45...you would want to see a row for visit 3,5,and 6?  Or just one row showing the most recent (6th) visit was over a 10 change?

Comment: I want to see a row for visit 3,5, and 6 in your example. Is it also possible to query from the first visit for each subsequent visit? In the second case, it'd be 3, 4, 5,and 6?

Comment: @user1828605 - edit for part 2 in...part 3 is being worked on now

Comment: @user1828605 - edits done.  I don't have a working mssql environment to test this in (written in notepad) so I'm hoping my syntax is correct, might be a few smaller errors (I noticed I missed a 'from' line in part 2)...let me know if you have any issues here

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much.