# Calculating space savings for sparse columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

According to the [SQL Server documentation for sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Consider using sparse columns when the space saved is at least 20 percent to 40 percent.

And there are tables that show the percentage of data that must be NULL to achieve a "net space savings of 40%" based on the size of the data type. Here's a summary:

```
Nonsparse bytes  Sparse bytes  NULL percentage
---------------  ------------  ---------------
 1                5            86%
 2                6            76%
 3                7            69%
 4                8            64%
 5                9            60%
 6               10            57%
 8 (bigint)      12            52%
10               14            49%
```

Questions:

1. How were the above NULL percentages calculated?

   I'm having trouble figuring out the math. For example, consider the row for **bigint**. If 52% of values in a sparse **bigint** column are NULL, then the 48% of non-NULL values should require 12 bytes × 48% = 5.76 bytes on average, which is 8 − 5.76 = 2.24 bytes less compared to a nonsparse column. But this is a savings of 2.24 bytes ÷ 8 bytes = 28%, not 40%.
2. What percentage of data must be NULL to achieve a space savings of 20%?

The post [Why & When should I use SPARSE COLUMN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398453) doesn't answer either question.

Comment: You’d save a lot of money and future hassle just buying slightly larger disks now and never enabling this feature. For example, if your table is big enough where this will actually matter, it’s probably also big enough where you may eventually want to perform changes online. Sparse columns prevent you from doing that. _Just not worth it._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why & When should I use SPARSE COLUMN? (SQL SERVER 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398453/why-when-should-i-use-sparse-column-sql-server-2008)